# canvas.toDataUrl() returns 'data:,'

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to resize an image and get back the base64 string representation using canvas.toDataUrl().

My code is as follows (see below). My issue is that every time when I first initiate it, it returns 'data:,'.

Then when I redo the re-sizing (calling with button), then it works fine and it returns me a nonempty base64 string. What is going on?

```
 function drawAndResizeFunction(images)
 var qDraw = $q.defer();

// 1
        drawCanvasWrapper().then(function(canvasData){
            qDraw.resolve(canvasData)
        });

        // 2
        function drawCanvasWrapper() {
            var pResults = images.map(function (imageObj) {
                //return drawCanvassIter(imageObj.tempURL); // tempUrl
                return resizeIter(imageObj.tempURL).then(function(result){
                    console.log("resized", result) // *** RETURNS data:, in first attempt
                     return result;
                })
            });
            return $q.all(pResults);
        };

        // 3inval
        // returns canvasdata
        function resizeIter(nativeURL) {

            console.log("resizeIter")

            var qResize = $q.defer();

            var canvas = document.getElementById("resizecanvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = nativeURL;

            var newScales = resizeDimensions(img.width, img.height)

            var iw  =canvas.width   =img.width      =newScales.iw;
            var ih  =canvas.height  =img.height     =newScales.ih;

            img.onload = function () {

                // --> 4
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, iw, ih);
                $timeout(function(){
                    qResize.resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
                }, 200)


            };

            return qResize.promise;



            //
            //
            function resizeDimensions(iw, ih) {
                var scaleFactor = 1;
                var targetSize = 800;

                if (iw > targetSize || ih > targetSize) {
                    if(iw > ih) {
                        scaleFactor = targetSize/iw;
                    } else {
                        scaleFactor = targetSize/ih;
                    }
                }
                var iwAdj = Math.floor(iw*scaleFactor);
                var ihAdj = Math.floor(ih*scaleFactor);

                return {
                    ih: ihAdj, iw: iwAdj
                }
            };
        };

return qDraw.promise; 
    }; // done
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code doing canvas to dataurl? Right now it sounds like a race issue, do you have it called on ready/load? Or an ajax function?

Comment: I use angular and call the function drawAndResizFunction from my controller. This function is available in the service. Do you need the HTML?

Comment: The strange thing is that it does not always happen...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The Cause

The reason is that the canvas has [invalid size](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-canvas-element):

> [...] The one exception to this is if the canvas has either no height or no
>   width, in which case the result might simply be "data:,".

Invalid size is including anything < 1.

When an image element doesn't have data loaded the width and height properties are 0 by default until the image has been fully loaded and decoded into a bitmap, at which time triggers the `onload` handler:

```js
var img = new Image();
document.write("w: " + img.width + " h: " + img.height);
```

## The Solution

Make sure the image has loaded before reading any size from it (simplified example, adopt as seen fit for your code):

```js
var img = new Image();
var w, h;
img.onload = function() {
    w = this.width;     // here we can extract image size
    h = this.height;
    // set canvas size here as well before drawing the image in
    // continue you code from here using f.ex. a callback
    document.write("w: " + w + " h: " + h);
};
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/eekEotAb.jpg";  // set src last
```

Comment: @markE yup, most of it must go inside in fact, but the answer gives an outline OP should be able to implement seeing the key issue, I hope :)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. will use this setup also in my next projects.

Answer (score 1):

The image has not yet fully loaded when you are calling `resizeDimensions`. And you're attempting to resize the canvas before the img dimensions have been set.

Put that code inside your `img.onload` handler so the image is guaranteed to be fully loaded.