# img.onload refuses to fire after new Image() declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load an image on to a canvas so I can write some text on it and maybe save it later on. I have two below functions:

```
openImage = (memeURL, index) => {

    this.setState({currentMeme: index}, () => {

        const base_image = new Image();

        base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        base_image.src = memeURL;

        const base64 = this.getBase64Image(base_image);

        this.setState({currentImagebase64: base64});
    })


}

getBase64Image(img) {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL;
}
```

The `openImage` function is bound to an `onClick` event so when I click an image it fires up the above operations so that my `<img src="">` can feed from state and display the image.

The problem is that when i click the image it never shows up and my `currentImagebase64` state value is always `data;` **BUT** if debug with web tools it appears fine because theres enough time for the image to load. Aparrently the solution is in the below answer:

[canvas.toDataUrl() returns 'data:,'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079423/canvas-todataurl-returns-data)

However, if I write something like suggested the `onload` function never triggers. For example below code won't trigger the onload for some reason, it just stops executing when it reaches it:

```
openImage = (memeURL, index) => {

    this.setState({currentMeme: index}, () => {

        const base_image = new Image();

        base_image.onload = function() {

            this.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

        }

        //Set src AFTER the image has loaded
        base_image.src = memeURL;

        const base64 = this.getBase64Image(base_image);

        this.setState({currentImagebase64: base64});
    })


}
```

Can any subject experts lend a hand please?

Comment: Try adding the image to the page DOM (as a hidden element) to trigger the src loading.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet as an example please? I have an existing `<img>` which src feeds from state, so are you suggesting fetching that `<img>` element and amending the src and `onload` will fire?

Comment: `this.crossOrigin = "anonymous";` need to be outside of onload, before you're assign the value to src.

Comment: `const base64 = this.getBase64Image(base_image);this.setState({currentImagebase64: base64});` would also be done INSIDE the onload

Comment: and `base_image.onload = function() {` should be `base_image.onload = () => {` otherwise `this` is `base_image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const base64 = this.getBase64Image(base_image);
this.setState({currentImagebase64: base64});
```

needs to be executed once the image has loaded

and

```
base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

needs to be done before setting the `src`

So, the code becomes

```
openImage = (memeURL, index) => {
    this.setState({currentMeme: index}, () => {
        const base_image = new Image();
        base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        base_image.onload = () => { // use arrow function so `this` will be what is needed
            const base64 = this.getBase64Image(base_image);
            this.setState({currentImagebase64: base64});
        }
        base_image.src = memeURL;
    })
}
```

Your comment

```
//Set src AFTER the image has loaded
```

suggests you don't know how onload works ... you set src which starts loading the image, and then onload is triggered when image finishes loading

Comment: Thanks. Yeah sorry for the confusion I meant after the code reaches the `onload` method for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* sure how react handles the states as above but I've had a similar issue in vanilla JS in which the src wasn't loading until added to the DOM. Keeping it hidden was fine though:

```
const image = new Image();
image.onload = (e)=>{
    // do something
}
image.src = YOUR_IMAGE_PATH;
image.hidden = true;

// add to body
document.body.appendChild(image); // at this point the src is loaded and onload handler is fired
```

Comment: I don't think you need to add element to the page to trigger downloading of images, but you need to assign src after you add onload event.